# Where can I view the statistics on N-400 case transfers between USCIS field offices?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

N-400 applications may be transferred between USCIS field offices, e.g. if the applicant moved or if an USCIS field office decides to [offload](https://www.passage.law/blog/uscis-may-transfer-some-cases-to-other-jurisdictions) some of their N-400 applications to another USCIS field office. Where can I view the statistics on N-400 case transfers between USCIS field offices?

Comment: I don't see how past statistics can help you. Anecdote: I had some immigration paperwork years ago that took many (6+) more months than expected due to an internal corruption scandal. They had suspended all application processing for a while. If I had asked "How long does the London office typically take to process X application", I would have got an answer that was true (say a couple of months), but unhelpful for me. if I had asked "What is the probability of a corruption scandal suspending applications for 6 months", the answer would have been (effectively) zero.  Either way, not helpful.

Comment: @GregHewgill it helps predict future trends.

Comment: Maybe, if you get a lot of data, but my point is it doesn't really help you predict anything about *your* application.

Comment: @GregHewgill It does. Probability theory 101.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt probability theory 101 teaches us that it is improbable to drown in a pool with an average depth of an inch, while statistics 101 teaches us that it is possible. Neither one will help *you* decide if *you* want to swim in *one specific* pool.

Comment: @littleadv exactly, that's why I am asking for data, not your opinion

Comment: I answered your question. Waiting to see what use you'll make of that information.

Comment: This question seems pretty pointless to me without explaining why it matters if an application is transferred between field offices. Does it somehow disadvantage the applicant eg by delaying the decision process? If it doesn’t matter then filing a FOIA request is a waste of USCIS time (edit: having now read the link, possibly such FOIA requests are behind the ‘misallocation of resources’ claimed in the report)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the information you are looking for you need to file a FOIA request with the USCIS. Here's [how to do it](https://www.uscis.gov/records/request-records-through-the-freedom-of-information-act-or-privacy-act).

Posting whatever data here would be pointless, even if anyone here had it, since it would become stale and useless quickly and would only end up misleading future readers.

Answer (score 1):

One can look at the [USCIS quarterly reports](https://www.uscis.gov/tools/reports-and-studies/immigration-and-citizenship-data?topic_id%5B%5D=33692&ddt_mon=&ddt_yr=2022&query=&items_per_page=10) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YueB8.png)). They give an interesting breakdown per USCIC field office, [e.g.](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/data/N400_performancedata_fy2022_qtr3.pdf) for the USCIC field offices in Washington state in 2022 Quarter 2 (April 1, 2022 to June 30, 2022):

[image]

Aggregating these tables over several quarters, e.g. for the Spokane field office, ignoring the military applications (negligible):

| Year | Quarter | Received | Approved | Denied | Pending |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Q3 | 214 | 350 | 39 | 476 |
| 2022 | Q2 | 295 | 451 | 83 | 597 |
| 2022 | Q1 | 218 | 282 | 34 | 857 |
| 2021 | Q4 | 256 | 49 | 43 | 1,259 |
| 2021 | Q3 | 278 | 177 | 20 | 1,698 |
| 2021 | Q2 | 226 | 396 | 30 | 530 |
| 2021 | Q1 | 241 | 213 | D | 751 |
| 2020 | Q4 | 342 | 186 | D | 731 |
| 2020 | Q3 | 185 | 236 | 13 | 559 |
| 2020 | Q2 | 259 | 160 | 24 | 651 |
| 2020 | Q1 | 311 | 207 | 19 | 533 |
| 2019 | Q4 | 312 | 264 | 28 | 434 |
| 2019 | Q3 | 273 | 298 | 25 | 392 |
| 2019 | Q2 | 294 | 278 | 27 | 445 |
| 2019 | Q1 | 275 | 213 | 20 | 425 |
| 2018 | Q4 | 307 | 332 | 18 | 371 |
| 2018 | Q3 | 303 | 417 | 25 | 419 |
| 2018 | Q2 | 292 | 205 | 22 | 590 |
| 2018 | Q1 | 215 | 228 | 22 | 521 |
| 2017 | Q4 | 250 | 262 | 24 | 551 |
| 2017 | Q3 | 299 | 234 | 17 | 611 |
| 2017 | Q2 | 336 | 280 | 12 | 567 |
| 2017 | Q1 | 263 | 169 | 14 | 577 |
| 2016 | Q4 | 228 | 213 | 26 | 489 |
| 2016 | Q3 | 269 | 274 | 12 | 613 |
| 2016 | Q2 | 346 | 190 | 18 | 512 |
| 2016 | Q1 | 241 | 235 | 16 | 361 |
| 2015 | Q4 | 221 | 243 | 11 | 349 |
| 2015 | Q3 | 255 | 196 | 8 | 391 |
| 2015 | Q2 | 280 | 191 | 14 | 351 |
| 2015 | Q1 | 186 | 180 | 30 | 274 |
| 2014 | Q4 | 191 | 214 | 14 | 276 |
| 2014 | Q3 | 231 | 215 | 12 | 294 |
| 2014 | Q2 | 218 | 184 | 24 | 288 |
| 2014 | Q1 | 160 | 180 | 21 | 269 |
| 2013 | Q4 | 203 | 249 | 24 | 307 |

E.g., we see:

| Year | Quarter | Received | Approved | Denied | Pending |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Q3 | 278 | 177 | 20 | 1,698 |
| 2021 | Q2 | 226 | 396 | 30 | 530 |

This means that in 2021 Q3 1087 (= 1698 - (530 + 278 - 177 - 20)) cases were transferred to Spokane, assuming no cases were withdrawn (very rare).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YeRoAOAtGsInGRjNgkNw1RrWbAtEDIysrs_lNcTRT7M/edit#gid=2073731705 gives all data for USCIS field offices in Washington state. Source: https://www.visajourney.com/forums/topic/777405-n-400-seattle-part-2/?do=findComment&comment=10748860